# Transfer variable from powershell script to batch

Tags: variables, powershell, batch-file

I'm running .bat scripts in my powershell script with code:

```
cmd.exe /c ($scriptsDir + "myBat.bat")
```

And i define some variables in PS, for ex.

```
$batDir = "C:\Users\...\...\...\"
```

And how in .bat I can use once defined $batDir variable?

Comment: what about a command line argument used in `mybat` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just put this line somewhere at the beginning in your bat file

```
set "$batDir=%~1"
```

and call the bat like

```
cmd.exe /c ($scriptsDir + "myBat.bat" + " " + $batDir)
```